# Как растянуть столбец по содержимому JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Здравствуйте! Суть проблемы: Есть JTable, заранее неизвестно какой длины текст внесет туда пользователь. Как растянуть столбцы по содержимому?

Вот мой код:

```
JTable tableWithData = new JTable(tableModel);
    tableWithData.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    tableWithData.editCellAt(1, 1);
    tableWithData.setRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
    tableWithData.setColumnSelectionInterval(1, 1);
    tableWithData.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    tableWithData.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    tableWithData.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRender());
    tableWithData.requestFocus();
    tableWithData.setSelectionMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    JPanel tmp = new JPanel();
    tmp.add(tableWithData);
    JScrollPane scrollForTabele = new JScrollPane(tmp);
    scrollForTabele.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    panelForTable.add(scrollForTabele);
```

В setSelectionMode() перепробывал уже все варианты - ничего не помогает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код из [ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570812):

```
JTable table = new JTable(){
       @Override
       public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
           Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
           int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
           TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
           tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth + getIntercellSpacing().width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
           return component;
        }
    };
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Код при перерисовке ячейки берет предпочитаемую ширину для компонента рисования ячейки, и устанавливает ее, как ширину столбца, если ширина столбца меньше. Изменение предпочитаемой ширины вызовет еще одну перерисовку таблицы. Если у вас длинная таблица, то ширина столбцов будет меняться по мере появления на экране ячеек с большим содержимым.

В [другом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037771) есть пример установки ширины и высоты ячеек таблицы отдельным методом.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но это перестает работать если сделать table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); Можно ли как то решить эту проблему?